# org mode: programmatically open element

Tags: org-mode

Code:

```
(let ((parsetree (org-element-parse-buffer 'element)))
  ; find the appropriate src element and jump to it
  (org-element-map parsetree 'src-block
    (lambda (elem)
      (let ((name (org-element-property :name elem)))
        ; str is the name of the element, we are searching for
        (when (equal name str)
          (goto-char (org-element-property :begin elem))
          (org-reveal)))))) ; <- doesn't work
```

It jumps to the src element in the current buffer with name equal to str (used for literate programming). Unfortunately, sometimes the element is closed, so I have to open it manually. `(org-reveal)` doesn't work. Is there any function to open the src element `elem`?

Comment: Can you add to your question the version of Org mode you are using? `M-x org-version` will report that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of the function to unfold the source block at  point that should work for Org mode versions before 9.5.4 (including 9.1.9):

```el
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/org-show-block ()
    (let* ((e (org-element-at-point))
           (type (org-element-type e)))
      (when (eq type 'src-block)
        (org-hide-block-toggle 'off nil e))))
#+end_src
```

It should behave identically to the function below  (which only works for version 9.5.4 and above).

---

##### Original answer

[Original answer starts here: it uses `org-fold.el` so it requires a fairly recent version of Org mode: 9.5.4 and above.]

Here's a little function to unfold the current element-at-point, given that it is a `src-block`:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/org-show-block ()
    (let* ((e (org-element-at-point))
           (type (org-element-type e))
           (beg (org-element-property :begin e))
           (end (org-element-property :end e)))
      (when (eq type 'src-block)
          (org-fold-region beg end nil 'block))))
#+end_src
```

It's a no-op if the block is already unfolded.

EDIT: here's another version of this function that is very similar to the one at the top of the answer. It uses an `org-fold` function so that it will work in version 9.5.4 or later of Org mode:

```el
 #+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/org-show-block ()
    (let* ((e (org-element-at-point))
           (type (org-element-type e)))
      (when (eq type 'src-block)
        (org-fold-hide-block-toggle 'off nil e))))
#+end_src
```

As you can see the only difference is the function name.

EDIT: It may be that you are using an old version of Org mode that does not have `org-fold.el`. `org-fold` is available in Org mode 9.5.4 and later. Emacs 28.2 currently comes with Org mode 9.6 I think, so that should work, but earlier version probably will not.

Comment: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-fold-region. What is it? I have fresh Emacs.

Comment: At home I have org mode 9.1.9. Will tell you the version at work as soon as I get there.

Comment: OK - that's too old : `org-fold.el` was added early last year. What version of emacs are you running? `M-x emacs-version` will tell.

Comment: GNU Emacs 26.3 of 2019-08-29. Trying to upgrade org-mode.

Comment: FYI: Note the [Org mode policy](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-maintenance.html#emacs-compatibility) for what versions of Emacs are supported: currently the latest [Emacs release](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/history.html) is 28.2, so Org mode supports Emacs 28, 27 and 26. When Emacs 29 is released (I don't know when that will be), Org mode support for Emacs 26 will be dropped (that does not mean that recent Org mode versions will not work with Emacs 26, but if there *is* breakage, there will be no guarantee that it will be fixed).

Comment: At work: Org mode version 9.5.2, GNU Emacs 28.1 of 2022-05-31.

Comment: I installed fresh org-mode from the git repository. Your code works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this is what you want. This checks if there is invisible text at the end of the src line, and if so toggles the hiding.

```
(require 'ov)

(let ((parsetree (org-element-parse-buffer 'element)))
                    ; find the appropriate src element and jump to it
  (org-element-map parsetree 'src-block
    (lambda (elem)
      (let ((name (org-element-property :name elem)))
                    ; str is the name of the element, we are searching for
        (when (equal name "name")
          (goto-char (org-element-property :begin elem))
      (save-excursion
        (forward-line 1)
        (end-of-line)       
        (when (and (ov-at) (overlay-get (ov-at) 'invisible))
          (org-hide-block-toggle))))))))
```

You might try `org-cycle` instead, but it is less specific to src blocks.

Comment: Symbol’s function definition is void: ov-at. `org-cycle` may close an opened block, which shouldn't be done, so I decided not to use it.

Comment: you have to (require 'ov) I added that to the solution above.